# Convert to string, remove some parts and convert back to byte[]

Tags: c#, string, filter, arrays

I need to delete the first 4 sentences of a byte[] converted to a string.

What I have so far:

```
//convert bytearray to string, so I can modify the string
string rawString = Convert.ToBase64String(rawByteArray);

//seperate lines
string[] textLines = Regex.Split(rawString, "\r\n");

//I need to substract the first 4 senctences of the string here!

//convert string back to byte array
byte[] cleanByteArray = rawstring.FromBase64String(rawString);
```

How do I substract the first 4 sentences?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "sentences"?  How is that found by looking at the string?  Ending in `\n`, for instance.

Comment: Indeed. In an abstract sense a sentence could also end in one or three dots, an exclamation, an interrogation mark, or a semicolon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Encoding.GetString` not Base64 string.

```
var newstr = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf)
                                .Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' })
                                .Skip(4));

buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newstr);
```